# Перезапись url в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим создан произвольный тип записи с таким названием: `custom_post`.
Есть страница, на которой выводится список этих записей нового типа, по примеру записей блога.
Но при открытии отдельной записи `custom_post`, `url` выглядит так:
`http://site.ru/custom_post/custom_postname`
Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы `url` новой записи выглядел по типу записей блога, к примеру так:
`http://site.ru/custom_postname`
В настройках `Постоянных ссылок` выбрана опция:
`Название записи - http://site.ru/sample-post/`

Comment: Покажите как вы создали произвольный тип.

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev, новый тип создан с помощью плагина Custom Post Type UI

Comment: такое же поведение будет, если создать новый тип стандартными средствами `register_post_type( 'custom_post' , $args );`

Comment: Нашёл ответ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-204210 .  
подскажите, как в этой строке указать все имеющиеся типы записей?:`$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'events', 'page' ) );` т.е. как это сделать правильно, если имеется несколько типов кастомных записей